# Designing objects for a chess game in java

Tags: java, oop

I am designing a chess game in Java (no AI, only user-controlled), and still getting used to OOP. I have two questions.

I was thinking of having, in addition to `Game`, `Cell`, `Piece` and `Board` objects, a `Player` object.

My question is, do I really need to? Of course I don't need to, but is either option considered better design? On the one hand, it seems a Player is useful for containing information about player pieces and should contain such methods as `takeTurn()`. (For my implementation, I also want to keep track of all possible moves, so I'll have a method `getAllMoves()`). On the other hand, isn't Player simply a reorganization of existing data? Each Piece already has an indication of which player it belongs to. And since my game contains no AI, it might make sense for `takeTurn()` to belong to `Game`, rather than `Player`. On the first hand again, maybe `Player` can have only the method `getAllMoves()`, which uses its data but does not take action.

The second question, relevant if the answer to the first question is yes, is how do I organize the relations between the objects? `getAllMoves()` will take in as input an array of cells; but it feels strange that then the Player class depends on the fact that its cells match (are a subset of) the cells passed in as input. It would feel more OK if the cells-divided-by-player data would be kept together with the array of all cells in Board, and updated together, thus guaranteeing that they agree. Of course, the guarantee that they agree would exist either way, but it seems that the Player object shouldn't be aware of a guarantee taking place in the `Board` object.

How do I deal with these questions?

Thanks!

Comment: It sounds as though you're attempting a [BDUF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_Design_Up_Front) - perhaps you might consider an alternative means of driving out your object model, like [TDD](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd882516.aspx)

Comment: BTW I think designing a game like chess is a very good approach to becoming familiar with OOP. Remember to favour associatons by interface over direct subclasses because the latter create an tight coupling which is not always necessary.

Answer (score 2):

IMHO having a Player object is a good design.
You can even refine it later to an interface an have an AIPlayer and HumanPlayer implementation.
Today you need only the getAllMoves method but later you might need more. Having an object will help you to extend yout player hability.

For your second point, I'm not sure that the Player should implements directly the getAllMoves() method.

I would have delegate that to the ChessGame object. Player will in this case have a reference to the Game and delegates the getAllMoves call to this Game instance, like this:

pseudo-code :)

> hey Game, what are the available moves for this piece ?

Comment: I agree. Having getAllMoves inside Player would sort of make it omniscient. There's the risk that this approach will lead to piling up a lot of logic inside one class. In real-life a Player could be seen as evaluating possible moves by looking at the board. This could be transposed as a message reflecting the pseudo-code you've given.

Comment: Thanks! I had thought a Player shouldn't have reference to the Game, but I guess it makes sense that it does. Another place I'm tripping up is the Piece. It seems that it should store logic for the different moves available for the different pieces -- that's why I created a class for each piece type. But again, to determine whether it can make a move, it must know about surrounding cells. Is that something the Game or Piece should do?

Comment: @user880129, it is a really good thing to ask yourself this question, and I'm still losing myself in this kind of consideration. Sometime OOP make us think too much :) For your case I will create a central class, that will act as a hub and able to answer all game state related question, like: is this cell is free, which are surrounding pieces, is this move's outside the board, ... So the piece will only contains the move description and small logic. Maybe you should try to find an open source chess game to look how it is done. This can help you to build your own system.

Answer (score 1):

The question of whether you need a 'Player' object - ask yourself if this object has any interaction/relationships to other objects in your system. Also, does it have any data or state information you might want to record? I can think of a couple of things you might want to keep track of related to a player - pieces captured, maybe a points score.

BTW it might be a good idea to construct an object model to visualise how the objects relate to each other. This will also give you a better idea of the interfaces between objects, and the methods required.

Comment: ...player name, colour played

Answer (score 1):

Are you familiar with UML and more specifically with Use Case and Sequence diagrams? This sounds like an exercice in modelization and it would be a good idea to also look up the notion of domain model.

Use Case actors like Player are usually transposed as classes (aka substitutes). Other classes can be determined by starting with a rough sequence diagram for each Use Case with your Actor class on one side and a global System class on the other.

This System class can be gradually decomposed as you go through the different messages. If a method/messsage isn't directly to a single instance of a class and it's attributes/internal state the chances are that it belongs elsewhere (ex: a BankAccount class does not have the same responsability as a BankAccountManager class). You can group the methods according to nature and you should see some other classes appear.

From there on it should be a simple case of determining if any 1-to-1, one-to-many and many-to-many relations exist between them. In Java these will be represented by single instances or Lists and directionality (does class A know about class B or is it a one-way street?) is represented by the presence or absence of references inside respective classes.

P.S: Note that what I'm loosely describing is an approach to methodology while UML simply contents itself with describing a system from different views.